# How can I receive BTC assets via BNB (Binance Smart) Chain Network

Tags: scam, user-safety

I received the information that BTC assets arrived in my Coinbase Wallet, as I was expecting to receive it.
However, when clicking on such BTC assets there's a message saying " This asset is in BNB (Binance Smart) Chain Network ".
I asked the sender to inform me about how to effectively receive the BTC assets, and I received the information that I need to have BNB assets in my Coinbase Wallet to pay as fee for the transaction.
The total amount of BTC assets in such transaction is 9.404 BTC, and the sender informed me that I need about 8000 USD in BNB, in my Coinbase Wallet, to enable the transaction to take place.
Currently, I don't have 8000 USD available to purchase BNB.
My questions are:

1. For how long such BTC assets are available in such status?
2. Is a time  deadline applicable somehow to make the transaction?
3. Is this transaction safe?
4. Is there any risk of purchasing 8K USD in BNB to pay the transaction, and then the transaction doesn't take place, losing the BNB assests?
   Please see related screenshot as er the attached picture.

Comment: This is not how blockchains work, so it is likely some scam. You do not need to hold or buy any tokens or coins to receive cryptocurrencies.

Answer (score 0):

dont pls. typical scam. you lose all of usdt